# How to call a method of a 3rd class by calling the method of the 2nd class from the 1st class

Tags: java, class, methods, return-value

I have one class naming 'Artist' from this class I can call the public method getArtists of class 'Track' which in the return value gives me an array of another class 'ArtistSimplified'. I am in interested in the method getName which returns a string of ArtistSimplified class. I want to know how to do it. I can not directly call the getName method of ArtistSimplified class.

```
        List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<>();
        tracks = Arrays.asList(topTracksRequest.execute());
        if(tracks == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(new ErrorMessage("No songs found for this id:" +artistId));
        }

        List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Song song = new Song();
            song.setTitle(tracks.get(i).getName());
            song.setArtist(tracks.get(i).getArtists().getClass().getMethod("getName", ArtistSimplified.class).getReturnType());
        }
```

I am stuck here. 
song.setArtist(tracks.get(i).getArtists().getClass().getMethod("getName", ArtistSimplified.class).getReturnType());

I tried the above line but it does not work.

Comment: Whats the `Artist` class look like?

Comment: Do you have the access-modifiers for your code?

Comment: Artist is the class I am calling these methods of other classes from.

Comment: The methods are public i can call them using class object.

Comment: tracks.get(i).getArtists() gives me the return value which is an Array of ArtistSimplified class. In this class there is a method getName which returns a string i need this string value to set to song.setArtist method.

Comment: "I can not directly call the getName method of ArtistSimplified class." can you explain why??

Comment: Because I will not get required artist name else I will get some other value.

Comment: I see nothing in the piece of code that prevents direct call to the getName() method.  what is the type of return value of `getArtists()`?

Comment: public ArtistSimplified[] getArtists() {
    return artists;
  }
Its artists which is an array of ArtistSimplified class.

Comment: so where is the problem? do you know how to iterate and access items in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to call `getName()` on the array itself. You need to inform an index  to which `Artist` you're going to get the name from.

```
for (int a = 0; a < tracks.get(i).getArtists().length; a++) { 
        System.out.print(tracks.get(i).getArtists()[a].getName()); 
}
```